# Android camera application (where is on file system locates *.apk)

Tags: android

I can't find where on filesystem of android locates camera application `*.apk`.

I looked `/system/app/`, `/system_ext/app/` but didn't found.
May be this application locates in another path, i don't know.
I'm android junior, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find the camera APK in the /system/app/ directory, you can try checking the /system/priv-app/ directory as well. Some system applications, including the camera, may be placed in this directory instead.

Comment: I think that camera.apk locates in the android firmware. Thank for all!